# How to save tiff images into a new npy file?

Tags: python, image, multidimensional-array, save, tiff

I would like to save some tiff images I have into a new npy file.

My data are saved in 5 different files (tiff format). I want to access to each one of them, convert them in narray and then save them in a new npy file (for deep learning classification).

```
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image
import os

Data_dir = r"C:\Desktop\Université_2019_2020\CoursS2_Mosef\Stage\Data\Grand_Leez\shp\imagettes"
Categories = ["Bouleau_tiff", "Chene_tiff", "Erable_tiff", "Frene_tiff", "Peuplier_tiff"]

for categorie in Categories:
    path = os.path.join(Data_dir, categorie) #path for each species
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        path_img = os.path.join(path,img)
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(path_img)) #load an image file
        imarray = np.array(im) # convert it to a matrix
        imarray = np.delete(imarray, 3, axis=2)
        np.save(Data_dir, imarray)
```

Problem: It's only return me the last observation of my last category `"Peuplier_tiff"`, also it's saved into the name `imagette`, I don't know why.

Last but not least, I have a doubt for my targets, how I can be sure that my categories are correctly assign to the corresponding arrays.

A lot of questions,
thanks in advance for your help.

S.V

Comment: you have to use unique  filenames when you save every file `np.save(Data_dir + "/" + unique_name, imarray)` But it seems your `Data_dir` is not path to directory and you have to first create it - ie. `os.makedirs(Data_dir)`

Comment: BTW: `os.path.join(path_img)` give the same path as direct `path_img`

Comment: Thanks  @furas , it's working. I now want to have each of my array in one specific nyp folder (for each species). One step at a time, see you from Belgium

Comment: `fullpath = os.path.join( specific_folder, filename )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response. Its working with this code :

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os


new_dir = "dta_npy"
directory = r"C:\Desktop\Université_2019_2020\CoursS2_Mosef\Stage\Data\Grand_Leez\shp\imagettes"
Data_dir = os.path.join(directory, new_dir)
os.makedirs(Data_dir)
print("Directory '%s' created" %Data_dir)

Categories = ["Bouleau_tif","Chene_tif", "Erable_tif", "Frene_tif", "Peuplier_tif"]

for categorie in Categories:
    path = os.path.join(directory,categorie) #path for each species
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(path,img)) #load an image file
        imarray = np.array(im) # convert it to a matrix
        imarray = np.delete(imarray, 3, axis=2)
        unique_name=img
        unique_name = unique_name.split(".")
        unique_name = unique_name[0]
        np.save(Data_dir+"/"+unique_name, imarray)
```

Now my objective is to format my data, for each of my class, in this way : (click on the link)

[format goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACcB3.png)

Comment: how to format data ? You shows only filenames. And if you want to format filenames then what is the problem - filename is a string and you can use any string's function - ie `f-string` `f"full_numpy_bitmap_{arg}.npy"` or `"full_numpy_bitmap_{arg}.npy".format(arg)` or `"full_numpy_bitmap_%s.npy" % (arg,)`

Comment: If you have new problem then create new question on new page